# How to merge hundreds of CSVs, each with millions of rows, using minimal RAM?

Tags: csv, bigdata, influxdb, sensors

I have terabytes of sensor data stored across separate CSV files in format timestamp and value. I need to merge these CSV files where I will have one column for timestamp (calculated as the average of all other timestamps for each row) and each sensor will have its own column where the column name comes from the file name. The number of sensors is more than 500. What tech stack to look into? I can't fit all data in RAM at once.

Example:

```
sensor1.csv
  timestamp  value
  10000        1.9
  10010        2.2
  ... (millions of rows)

sensor2.csv
  timestamp  value
  10004        3.5
  10012        4.3

... (500 more files)
```

Result should look like this (timestamp in this file is the average of all the timestamps from all 500+ input files, names of sensors, e.g. sensor1, sensor2 and etc., come from filenames):

```
merged_file.csv
timestamp  sensor1  sensor2   ...  sensor500
  10002      1.9      3.5            2.1
  10011      2.2      4.3            3.5
```

After merge, I would like to store data in a database, e.g. InfluxDB, for future analysis and model trainings. What tools would be best to perform merge and analysis operations on this data?

Comment: Thank you for trying to describe the problem. I’m still not sure what you have and what you are aiming for. Please edit your post include some samples of the inputs and what those inputs will look like in the final file… files.

Comment: @ZachYoung I have added a sample input/output. Hope it helps

Comment: Excellent sample data, thank you! I've edited your question and title a bit. I suggest you consider further editing this question by moving the Analysis/DB information to another SO question. Although, SO doesn't really like open-ended questions about "which tools/processes can I use?" I went and answered this because I wanted to do so for myself, and to see if I actually can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I see your post as two distinct questions: 1) How to merge 500 CSVs? 2) whatever comes next, some DB?

This is a solution for the first question.  I'm using Python, there are languages/runtimes that could do this faster, but I think Python will give you a good first start at the problem and I'm expecting Python will be more accessbile and easier to use for you.

***Also, my solution is predicated on the fact that all 500 CSVs have identical row counts.***

My solution opens all 500 CSVs at once, creates an outer loop over a set number of rows, and an inner loop over each CSV:

- The inner loop reads the timestamp and value for a row in each CSV, averaging the 500 timestamps into a single column, and accumulating the 500 distinct values in their own columns, and all that goes into a final merged row with 501 columns.
- The outer loop repeats that process for as many rows as there are across all 500 CSVs.

I generated some sample data, 500 CSVs each with 1_000_000 rows, for 6.5G of CSVs.  I ran the following script on my M1 Macbook Air.  It completed in 8.3 minutes and peaked at 34.6M of RAM and produced a final CSV that is about 2G on disk.

```py
import csv
import glob

# Fill this in based on your own knowledge, or, based on the output of 'analyze_stats.py'
NUM_ROWS = 1_000_000

sensor_filenames = sorted(glob.glob('sensor*.csv'))

# Sort: trim leading 6 chars, 'sensor', and trailing 4 chars, '.csv', leaving just the number in the middle
sensor_filenames = sorted(sensor_filenames, key=lambda x: int(x[6:-4]))

# Get handles to all files, and create input CSV readers
sensor_readers = []
for sensor_fname in sensor_filenames:
    f = open(sensor_fname, newline='')
    sensor_readers.append(csv.reader(f))

# Create output CSV writer
f = open('merged_sensors.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(f)

# Discard all sensor headers
for reader in sensor_readers:
    next(reader)

# Build up output header and write
output_header = ['timestamp']
for sensor_fname in sensor_filenames:
    sensor_name = sensor_fname[:-4]  # trim off '.csv'
    output_header.append(sensor_name)
writer.writerow(output_header)

row_count = 0
while row_count < NUM_ROWS:
    row_count += 1
    values = []
    timestamps = []
    for reader in sensor_readers:
        row = next(reader)

        ts, val = row
        timestamps.append(int(ts))
        values.append(val)
    
    if row_count % 1000 == 0:
        print(f'Merged {row_count} rows')
 
    avg_ts = int(sum(timestamps)/len(timestamps))
    writer.writerow([avg_ts] + values)
```

I haven't profiled this, but I believe the only real allocations of memory that add up are going to be:

- the 500 file handles and CSV readers (which is small) for the entirety of the process
- each row from the input CSVs in the inner loop
- the final merged row in the outer loop

At the top of the script I mention analyze_stats.py.  Even if this were my data, I'd be very patient and break down the entire process into multiple steps, each which I could verify, and I would ultimately arrive at the correct, final CSV.  This is especially true for me trying to help you, because I don't control the data or "know" it like you, so I'm going to offer up this bigger process:

1. Read all the CSVs and record some stats: headers, column counts, and especially row counts.
2. Analyze those stats for "conformance", making sure no CSVs deviates from your idea of what it should be, and especially get confirmation that all 500 CSVs have the same number of columns and rows.
3. Use the proven row count as input into the merge process.

   There are ways to write the merge script so it doesn't have to know "the row count" up front, but it's more code, it's slightly more confusing, and it won't help you if there ever is a problem... you probably don't want to find out on row 2 million that there was problem "somewhere", I know I hate it when that happens.

If you're new to Python or the CSV readers/writers I recommend you read these scripts first.

- [get_sensor_stats.py](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/d9f3c64886f0d24737e8d96880c2b9d8#file-get_sensor_stats-py): reads all your sensor data and records the header, the minimum and maximum number of columns seens, and the row count for each CSV; it writes all those stats out to a CSV
- [analyze_stats.py](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/d9f3c64886f0d24737e8d96880c2b9d8#file-analyze_stats-py): reads in the stats CSV and checks to make sure header and column counts meet pre-defined values; it also keeps a tally of all the row counts for each file, and if there are files with different row counts  it will let you know

Also, here's the script I used to generate my 6G of sample data:

- [gen_sensor_data.py](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/d9f3c64886f0d24737e8d96880c2b9d8#file-gen_sensor_data-py): is my attempt to meaningfully represent your problem space, both in size and complexity (which is very easy, thankfully )

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation and code samples! I have run so far the get_sensor_stats.py on the CSV files where the min row count is ~2.1M and max row count is ~2.7M. In the future, I will need to scale it for terabytes of data. Currently, the total size of all CSV files is ~50GB. The code snippet get_sensor_stats.py was taking more than 10 minutes to run for me, so I just interrupted it. Instead, I have used the Spark with count() method that processed all files in less than 2 minutes. Clearly, the choice of the correct tool matters a lot, so I wonder best tools for next steps.

Comment: Oh, wow, Spark looks a lot faster than Python (not surprising). I'm curious, what does it mean for your data when one sensor's file has more rows (data) than another... how do you know that rows from different sensors belong together, and that their timestamps should be averaged?

Answer (score 0):

Same big idea as [my Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70735017/246801), but in Go for a 2.5 minute speed-up and using 1/3 the RAM.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
)

// Fill this in based on your own knowledge, or, based on the output of 'analyze_stats.py'
const NUM_ROWS = 1_000_000

// Sorting sensor filenames by a custom key, the sensor number
type BySensorNum []string

func (sn BySensorNum) Len() int      { return len(sn) }
func (sn BySensorNum) Swap(i, j int) { sn[i], sn[j] = sn[j], sn[i] }
func (sn BySensorNum) Less(i, j int) bool {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`.*sensor(\d+).csv`)

    // Tease out sensor num from file "A"
    fnameA := sn[i]
    matchA := re.FindStringSubmatch(fnameA)
    numA := matchA[1]
    intA, errA := strconv.Atoi(numA)
    if errA != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Could not parse number \"%s\" from file-name \"%s\" as int: %v\n", errA, numA, fnameA))
    }

    // Tease out sensor num from file "B"
    fnameB := sn[j]
    matchB := re.FindStringSubmatch(fnameB)
    numB := matchB[1]
    intB, errB := strconv.Atoi(numB)
    if errB != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("%v: Could not parse number \"%s\" from file-name \"%s\" as int\n", errB, numB, fnameB))
    }

    // Compare sensor nums numerically
    return intA < intB
}

func main() {
    // filenames := []string{"../sensor1.csv", "../sensor2.csv", "../sensor3.csv", "../sensor4.csv", "../sensor5.csv", "../sensor6.csv", "../sensor7.csv", "../sensor8.csv", "../sensor9.csv", "../sensor10.csv"}
    filenames, err := filepath.Glob("sensor*.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // only expect error if Glob pattern is bad itself (malformed)
    }
    fileCount := len(filenames)
    sort.Sort(BySensorNum(filenames))

    // Create output CSV writer
    outFname := "merged_sensors.csv"
    f, err := os.Create(outFname)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Could not create \"%s\" for writing: %v", outFname, err))
    }
    defer f.Close()
    w := csv.NewWriter(f)

    // Get handles to all files, and create input CSV readers
    readers := make([]*csv.Reader, fileCount)
    for i, fname := range filenames {
        f, err := os.Open(fname)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("Could not open \"%s\": %v", fname, err))
        }
        defer f.Close()
        readers[i] = csv.NewReader(f)
    }

    // Discard all sensor headers
    for _, r := range readers {
        r.Read()
    }

    // With everything created or opened, start writing...

    // Build up output header and write
    header := make([]string, fileCount+1)
    header[0] = "timestamp"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`.*(sensor\d+)\.csv`)
    for i, fname := range filenames {
        sensorName := re.FindStringSubmatch(fname)[1]
        header[i+1] = sensorName
    }
    w.Write(header)

    // "Shell" of final record with fileCount+1 columns, create once and use over-and-over again
    finalRecord := make([]string, fileCount+1)

    for i := 1; i <= NUM_ROWS; i++ {
        var tsSum int
        for j, r := range readers {
            record, err := r.Read()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                panic(fmt.Errorf("Could not read record for row %d of file \"%s\": %v", i, filenames[j], err))
            }
            timestamp, err := strconv.Atoi(record[0])
            if err != nil {
                panic(fmt.Errorf("Could not parse timestamp \"%s\" as int in record `%v`, row %d, of file \"%s\": %v", record[0], record, i, filenames[j], err))
            }
            tsSum += timestamp
            finalRecord[j+1] = record[1]
        }
        // Add average timestamp to first cell/column
        finalRecord[0] = fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", float32(tsSum)/float32(fileCount))

        w.Write(finalRecord)
    }
    w.Flush()
}
```